# Правильное построение предложения и его суть

Tags: смысл

**Ваши контактные данные для обратной связи: ФИО, адрес, эл. почта, телефон (по желанию).**

Как надо понимать? Телефон пишется по желанию, или же все перечисленные данные?

Answer (score 2):

1) **Телефон по желанию**

Ваши контактные данные для обратной связи: ФИО, адрес,эл.почта,телефон (по желанию).

2) **Все перечисленные данные по желанию**

Ваши контактные данные для обратной связи (по желанию): ФИО, адрес,эл.почта,телефон.

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю это предложение так: ФИО, адрес, эл. почта — **обязательны** для предоставления; телефон — **по желанию**.

Если бы *по желанию* относилось ко всем данным, то предложение могло бы выглядеть так:

*Ваши контактные данные для обратной связи: ФИО, адрес, эл. почта, телефон (заполня**ются** по желанию).*
Но в таком предложении нет никакого смысла: я "по желанию" не заполню ни одной позиции и никакой обратной связи, соответственно, не будет.

Такая формулировка используется обычно в [**анкетах**](http://zelart.com.ua/anketa-dlya-registratsii.html), заявлениях, ходатайствах, и выглядит она, приблизительно, таким образом:

ФИО* . . . . . . .
Адрес* . . . . .
Эл. почта* . . . .
Образование . . . .
Телефон . . . . . .
_  _

- Поля, обязательные для заполнения.

Answer (score 1):

> Как вы понимаете это предложение?

Похоже на предложение из анкеты, поясняющее, какие сведения нужно поместить в текущей графе (например, обозначенной линиями, над которыми предлагается что-то вписать в анкету).

> Телефон пишется по желанию или же все перечисленные данные?

Помещённое в скобки "по желанию" относится только к текущему элементу перечисления (к телефону), в противном случае это уточнение следовало бы поместить перед двоеточием.